# Query through a relationship - laravel DB

Tags: laravel

how do I get the same result for this when I use Query Builder DB

```
$categories = Category::with(['subcategory' => function ($query) {
            return $query->where('status', true);
        }])->where('status', true)->get();
```

##### Relationships

category

```
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
    }
```

subcategory

```
       public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

tables
categories

```
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
```

subcategories

```
            $table->id();
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->  onUpdate('cascade');
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

I want to do a loop like this

```
 foreach ($categories as $ctaegory){
           $ctaegory->name
     foreach ($ctaegory->subcategory as $subcategory){
           $subcategory->name
     }
 }
```

#### My code works (Eloquent), but I want to use DB

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
DB::table('categories')
  ->join('subcategories', 'categories.id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
  ->where('subcategories.status', true)
  ->get();
```

I don't tested.

**OR**

```
Category::select("categories.*, subcategories.*")
 ->join("subcategories", "subcategories.category_id","=","categories.id")
 ->where('subcategories.status', true)
 ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only get subcategories, I added ->select('categories.*', 'subcategories.*'), but the result has not changed

Comment: @Ghiath Al-Khatib can you post the related column name? what kind of relation is that between category and subcategories?

Comment: @GhiathAl-Khatib I updatwed my answear. please try the secound query.

Comment: I updated a question, I want to use DB, Eloquent works

Comment: @GhiathAl-Khatib are you checked the secound Query? `Category::select("categories.*, subcategories.*")
 ->join("subcategories", "subcategories.category_id","=","categories.id")
 ->where('subcategories.status', true)
 ->get();
`